# Download the data from data base after second click

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Why the data is displayed after the second click?

Maybe I'm not doing the ajax request correctly. I want to output data from the database to the page and update after adding.

Can you find where the problem is?

*main.js*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'dataconnect.php',
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                $(".rows").html(data);
            }
        });
    });


    $("button.btnSubmit").on("click", function () {
        let textsval = $(".inputs_text").val();
        let imgsval = $(".inputs_img").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'bdconnect.php',
            type: "POST",
            data: { textss: textsval, imgg: imgsval },
        })
            .done(function () {
                // $(".rows").append(result);
            });
        $(".inputs_text").val("");
        $(".inputs_img").val("");


        $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'dataconnect.php',
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data) {
                    $(".rows").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

*dataconnect.php*

```
<?php
    require_once("bdconnect.php");

    $query = $db->query('SELECT * FROM `databd`.`infos`');
    while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo "<p>" . $row['texts'] . "</p>";
    }
?>
```

*bdconnect.php*

```
<?php

$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbname = "databd";
$username = "root";
$userpass = "";
$charset = "utf8";
$options = [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION];

$data = [
    "textss" => trim($_POST["textss"]),
    "imgg" => trim($_POST["imgg"]),
];

$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname = $dbname;charset=$charset", $username, $userpass, $options);
if (!empty(trim($_POST["textss"])) && !empty(trim($_POST["imgg"]))) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO `databd`.`infos`(texts,img) VALUES (:textss, :imgg)";
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $statement->execute($data);
};
```

Comment: After the first click, the data goes to the database but is not displayed in html. After the second click are displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that both ajax calls are made at the same time and when the `dataconnect` call is done the data is not yet in the server.

An ajax call runs async so even the `dataconnect` call is written later in the code the `bdconnect` call has not been completed yet. Not until the `done` callback is executed.

Place the `dataconnect` call in the `done` callback and you should see the data updated after adding anything.

And to improve the code you could define a function:

```
function refreshData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'dataconnect.php',
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            $(".rows").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

And use `$(refreshData)` to call it each time instead of repeating all the code as in *document.ready*.

The whole javascript code would be:

```
function refreshData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'dataconnect.php',
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            $(".rows").html(data);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(refreshData);

    $("button.btnSubmit").on("click", function () {
        let textsval = $(".inputs_text").val();
        let imgsval = $(".inputs_img").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'bdconnect.php',
            type: "POST",
            data: { textss: textsval, imgg: imgsval },
        }).done(function () {
            $(refreshData);
        });
        $(".inputs_text").val("");
        $(".inputs_img").val("");
    });
});
```